# gethostbyname_ex(hostname) extremely slow

Tags: python, sockets, ip-address, gethostbyname

At startup, IPython (qtconsole) calls `socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2]` to find a list of IP addresses that point to the machine.  On a Linux server that I manage this call is *extremely* slow (>20s)... which I have trouble understanding as `ip addr show` seems to give the same information nearly instantaneously.  Is there anything I can do to make this faster?  Can this be a network configuration issue (I am behind a router)?

This issue is independent of IPython:

```
$ time python -c 'import socket; print(socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2])' 
['192.168.0.102']
python -c   0.07s user 0.02s system 0% cpu 28.190 total
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem.
It happened that my hostname was `localhost.localdomain`, being lazy when installing the OS.

The solution was to give it a sane name by `sudo vi /etc/hostname` and changing it to myname.mydomain and now it runs in 1s.

Comment: To make sure it is as fast as possible I also added `myname.mydomain` and `myname.mydomain.local` to `/etc/hosts` to ip address 127.0.0.1