# IPython taking 30 seconds to start

Tags: python, ipython

I recently installed Anaconda, and with it, the IPython package. It takes close to a minute when running the command

```
ipython notebook
```

from the Windows cmd, but even running

```
ipython
```

to start up the environment takes close to 30 seconds. I've searched for answers, but I can't seem to get anything that directly relates to my problem.

Is there any way I can diagnose this, or is there a fix available?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076474/slow-ipython-pylab-and-ipython-notebook-startup

Comment: The problem on that thread is using --pylab. The poster of that question mentions that ipython starts without a problem. My ipython environment takes almost 30 seconds to load normally. Also, I cannot see any resolution with that question.