# IPython kernel dies on startup

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda

I am running Ubuntu 64-bit and using IPython from the Anaconda distribution. When I type "ipython notebook" in terminal, everything starts up as it should. But when I create a new notebook, or open an existing one, the kernel dies, tries to restart, and fails.

Here is the info from terminal for the entire session, with the errors:

```
[W 08:54:43.010 NotebookApp] ipywidgets package not installed.  Widgets are unavailable.
[I 08:54:43.018 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/eric
[I 08:54:43.018 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 08:54:43.018 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 08:54:43.018 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
Created new window in existing browser session.
[I 08:54:47.720 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in 
[W 08:54:48.468 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20150825085443 (127.0.0.1) 5.44ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled2.ipynb?kernel_name=python2
[I 08:54:48.529 NotebookApp] Kernel started: e595c923-cc96-4ab7-ae39-d2fe4eac1261
[I 08:54:51.531 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
[W 08:54:58.554 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from e595c923-cc96-4ab7-ae39-d2fe4eac1261
[I 08:55:00.535 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
WARNING:root:kernel e595c923-cc96-4ab7-ae39-d2fe4eac1261 restarted
*** stack smashing detected ***: /home/eric/anaconda/bin/python terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

When I use IPython (without the html) from the terminal, everything works fine. I have reinstalled IPython, but that did not change anything. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you launch without the extension `/nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js` does it still crash?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would I launch without the extension?

Comment: Never done it myself (I don't use the extension system), but this looks promising: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki#3-deactivating-extensions (or the next item to see what extensions are installed)

Comment: It doesn't look like I have any extensions, including the one you mention, so I don't think this is the issue. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run

```
import socket
print( '127.0.0.1 ' + socket.gethostname() + '.local' )
```

And add output to /etc/hosts
It will help if problem in socket.gethostbyname_ex

Related question [gethostbyname_ex(hostname) extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544514)

Also this may help

```
conda remove pyzmq
conda install pyzmq=14.6.0
```

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/297